# Where is my download folder?

Tags: boot, usb, unetbootin

I'm trying to create a Bootable USB with UNetBootin.However, when I click to search for my .iso it only shows `Computer` and inside that it has a `Home`and a `root` folder.

I really need to know how to get to my downloads folder through these folders because I don't have write permission in these folders.

Where is my download folder?

Comment: This would be easier to understand with a screenshot. Have you tried double clicking on the `/` and then going to `/home` -> your user name -> Downloads?

Answer (score 2):

Your home directory should be at `/home/USERNAME/Downloads`, where `USERNAME` is your username. You should be able to navigate there by opening `/`, then `home`, then `USERNAME` and `Downloads`.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse u will find download directory at `/home/USERNAME/Downloads/` make sure that you are selecting the right options in UNetBootin.

to run the `UNetBootin` the right way when it is in `Downloads`:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
chmod 777 unetbootin-linux64-661.bin
sudo ./unetbootin-linux64-661.bin
```

You could also use `startup disk creator` which is also a handy tool to create bootable disk. Most of the linux dist have it preinstalled. Mine was Ubuntu and that works justs fine.